# Exception lost after rethrow

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method `ValidarConexaoEPI` which validates a connection string trying to open a connection with it. In case of exceptions, the method who had call the "validate" one `SolicitarNovaSincronizacao`, catches it and rethrow a manipulated exception.

```
public static SincronizacaoSinc SolicitarNovaSincronizacao(int? idUsuario, int idAlmoxarifado, string versaoAplicacao, bool validaSincronizacaoEmAndatmento = true)
    {
        SincronizacaoSinc sincronizacaoSinc = null;

        using (var conexaoLocal = new SqlConnectionEPI(_DbLocalConnectionString))
        using (var conexaoServidor = new SqlConnectionEPI(_DbOnlineConnectionString))
        {
            sincronizacaoSinc = new SincronizacaoSinc(idUsuario, idAlmoxarifado, versaoAplicacao);

            try
            {
                if (UtilDataAccess.ValidarConexaoEPI(conexaoLocal) && UtilDataAccess.ValidarConexaoEPI(conexaoServidor))
                {
                    ValidarAlmoxarifadoBaseOnline(conexaoServidor, idAlmoxarifado);
                    ValidarUsuarioBaseOnline(conexaoServidor, idUsuario);

                    CriarRegistroSincronizacao(conexaoLocal, conexaoServidor, sincronizacaoSinc);

                    if(validaSincronizacaoEmAndatmento)
                    {
                        SolicitarSincronizacao(conexaoServidor, sincronizacaoSinc);
                    }                        

                    AtualizarRegistroSincronizacao(conexaoLocal, conexaoServidor, sincronizacaoSinc);
                }

                conexaoServidor.SqlTransaction.Commit();
                conexaoLocal.SqlTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format(
                    "Erro ao iniciar sincronizacao. {0}", exception.Message), exception.InnerException);
            }
        }

        return sincronizacaoSinc;
    }


public static bool ValidarConexaoEPI(SqlConnectionEPI conexao) //This method is in another static class
    {
        try
        {
            conexao.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlException)
        {
            var dataSource = conexao != null && conexao.SqlConnection != null
                ? conexao.SqlConnection.DataSource : "string de conexão inválida";

            throw new Exception(String.Format(
                "Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados ({0}).", dataSource), sqlException);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(String.Format(
                "Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados: {0}", exception.Message), exception);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

But, after rethrow I lost the exception data. The next method, the one who called the SolicitarNovaSincronizacao() receive a NullReference exception. As you can see:

Exception catch on ValidarConexaoEPI():

[image]

NullReference exception catch:

[image]

Every other exception catch by `SolicitarNovaSincronizacao` is ok, the problem occur just with this one. The exception used to mount the new one is ok.

PS.: I know that it is not the right use of try/catch! Not my code.

EDIT:

Here is the StackTrace of the NullReferenceException:

em AG.ControleEPI.Dados.SqlConnectionEPI.Dispose() na C:\Projetos\AG\TFS2013\ControleEPI\Main\Source-locais\AG.ControleEPI.Dados\ADO\SqlConnectionEPI.cs:linha 28
em AG.ControleEPI.Dados.ADO.SincronizacaoDataAccess.SolicitarNovaSincronizacao(Nullable`1 idUsuario, Int32 idAlmoxarifado, String versaoAplicacao, Boolean validaSincronizacaoEmAndatmento) na C:\Projetos\AG\TFS2013\ControleEPI\Main\Source-locais\AG.ControleEPI.Dados\ADO\SincronizacaoOnline\SincronizacaoDataAccess.cs:linha 50
em AG.ControleEPI.Negocio.Gerenciador.SincronizacaoGerenciador.IniciarSincronizacao(Int32 idUsuario, Int32 idAlmoxarifado, String versaoAplicacao) na C:\Projetos\AG\TFS2013\ControleEPI\Main\Source-locais\AG.ControleEPI.Negocio\GerenciadorCustomizado\SincronizacaoGerenciador.cs:linha 84

Comment: Side note: put `exception` itself, not `exception.InnerException` here `throw new Exception(String.Format(
                    "Erro ao iniciar sincronizacao. {0}", exception.Message), exception);`

Comment: I was initially using it. Just made the change trying to solve my problem. I appreciate!

Comment: You're still passing `exception.InnerException` inside `SolicitarNovaSincronizacao`, which could well be null...

Comment: Consider using English naming - it is a widely used practice and make it much easier for everyone: for people on StackOverflow trying to help you, for you as a developer to be able work in international projects or to relocate in future, for consumers of your code, for prospective international employees etc.

Comment: I'm passing just the exception, guys. The exception.InnerException was just a mad try to correct my problem as I said. Already made the change back! Thank you!

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I totally agree. Just working with anothers one code this time. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind adding the stacktrace when you get NullReferenceException ?

Comment: Done, @YeldarKurmangaliyev!

Comment: As you can see in StackTrace, the NullRefereneException is raised from `AG.ControleEPI.Dados.SqlConnectionEPI.Dispose()` method which is called because of your using() block.

Comment: You are right! Sorry about that... Problem solved!